# jQuery Countdown - reset timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I'm using the [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin and have a quick query.

My code currently looks like this:

```
function doCountdown(){
    var nextNoon = new Date();
    if (nextNoon.getHours()>=12){ nextNoon.setDate(nextNoon.getDate()+1); }
    nextNoon.setHours(11,30,0,0);

    $('h3 .timer strong').countdown({until: nextNoon, compact: true, 
        description: '',  onExpiry: function(){doCountdown()}});
}

$(window).load(function(){
     doCountdown();
});
```

So basically, it counts down untill the next `11:30AM`. However I need it to reset the counter when it reaches `11:30AM`, so it will automatically go to `23:59:59` on the timer.

Currently it just sticks at `00:00:00` even though the `doCountdown` function is called `onExpiry` (tested with `console.log` and it definitely calls it).

Is it because javascript bases the time off page load and then stores it?

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769296/456135)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your `nextNoon` creation miscalculates for times between 11:30am and 12:00pm. For that half an hour period, the `if()` will evaluate to false, so it will set the time as 11:30am of the current day. However we've already passed that time, since we're between 11:30am and 12noon. So the countdown will just go to zero.

You need to do as follows:

```
var todaysNoon = new Date(), nextNoon = new Date();
todaysNoon.setHours(11,30,0,0);
if (todaysNoon <= nextNoon){ nextNoon.setDate(nextNoon.getDate()+1); }
nextNoon.setHours(11,30,0,0);
```