# jquery countdown restart countdown without push any button

Tags: jquery, restart

I use this [jquery countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

What i want with the countdown is that it restart every day at 14:00. When the counter reach 14:00 o'clock it should restart automatically and go to 23h:59m:59s

Right now it count down and when it reach my time it sticks at 00:00:00. If i manually refresh the page the countdown starts again.

I have watch this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686188/jquery-countdown-reset-timer) but i wo't help me with the restart

Here is the code I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1      /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doCountdown() {
    var todaysNoon = new Date(),
        nextNoon = new Date();
    todaysNoon.setHours(14, 00, 0);
    if (todaysNoon <= nextNoon) {
        nextNoon.setDate(nextNoon.getDate() + 1);
    }
    nextNoon.setHours(14, 00, 0);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: nextNoon,
        description: '',
        onExpiry: function() {
            doCountdown()
        }
    });
}
$(window).load(function() {
    doCountdown();
});​
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<h1>Text here</h1>
<p>Some text here.</p>
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with countDown is that it each time use the same date to restart itself,so if you call countDown initialization function recursively it will use the old value to initialize itself and immediately call recursive function,because that value will the same as old(stored) one.
So I find a different solution and here's the code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        startCountDown();
    });

    function startCountDown() {
        var austDay = new Date();
        //        austDay.setMinutes(austDay.getMinutes() + 1);
        austDay.setSeconds(austDay.getSeconds() + 5);
        $('#myDiv').children().remove();
        $('#myDiv').append('<div id="defaultCountdown" />');

        $('#myDiv').find('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
            format: 'MS',
            until: austDay,
            onExpiry: function () {
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy');
                austDay.setMinutes(austDay.getMinutes() + 1);
                startCountDown();
            },
            compact: true,
            layout: '<b>{mnn}{sep}{snn}</b>'
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="defaultCountdown">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to illustrate proper use:

Simply do this - you were very close:

```
function doCountdown() {
    var todaysNoon = new Date(),
        nextNoon = new Date();
    todaysNoon.setHours(14, 00, 0);
    if (todaysNoon <= nextNoon) {
        nextNoon.setDate(nextNoon.getDate() + 1);
    }
    nextNoon.setHours(14, 00, 0);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: nextNoon,
        description: '',
        onExpiry: doCountdown
    });
}
$(window).load(function() {
    doCountdown();
});​
```

What you were doing was passing "the result" of your function to the callback, not the actual function itself

here's a JSfiddle I made for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/U6tgV/

edit one more tyne (looking @ your page):

If you copy this verbatim it works as you wrote it with mild restructuring. Please note that I verified this via a local installation of Apache HTTPD 2.x stable, PHP5.4.x stable and this is a literal copy paste from that.

Couple additional notes : "best practices" (how i loath that phrase) are that your html + css should be stand alone and JS should compliment it. That being said - js and js refs should occur as much as possible AFTER the html is established. This sounds a lot easier than it can be depending on legacy systems and render-chain processes. Good luck and happy hunting

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Countdown</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import "jquery.countdown.css";

#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="defaultCountdown">asdasdads</div>?
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function doCountdown() {
    var todaysNoon = new Date(),
        nextNoon = new Date();
    todaysNoon.setHours(0, 00, 30);
    if (todaysNoon <= nextNoon) {
        nextNoon.setDate(nextNoon.getDate() + 1);
    }
    nextNoon.setHours(00, 00, 60);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: nextNoon,
        description: '',
        onExpiry: doCountdown
    });
}
$('#defaultCountdown').on("click", function() {
    doCountdown();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know how to: "destroy the object and recreate it"

Comment: see edit above - that code is right from their FAQ. Countdown treats the object just like any interval object. You can clear it from the document like any setInterval object

Comment: Thanks,
Iam a newbie so i have no idea where to start / put the 
    var timerId =
      countdown(
        new Date(),
        function(ts) {
                document.getElementById('pageTimer').innerHT. ML =           ts.toHTML("strong");
        },
        countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);

     // later on this timer may be stopped
    window.clearInterval(timerId);

Comment: no worries man you were very close. Edited my answer and mentioned where you went wrong

Comment: Thanks, It seems to be something missing.. i copied the jsfiddle.net/U6tgV/ it won't show a countdown

Comment: yeah don't know what to tell you - working as intended for me - good luck.

Comment: thanks, if you have some more minutes please look at my source here: view-source:http://happy-cart.com/ i may have made something wrong..

Comment: Happy Friday - updated the post with a restructured (but not really changed) full html from that link you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your time, i have to edit the code someway to make it work.

Comment: I give up on this, takes to much time and never work. What i get to work is the countdown, but not the automatically restart (manually refresh page and it start again from 23:59:59) and without automatically the restart this is ugly if it sticks on 00:00:00. If i found a solution in the future i will post it here of course :)

Comment: arguably its such a simple task that you should really just write your own. good luck and happy hunting

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, here is what I did to solve it.
You are trying to re-initialize the plugin on expiry event, you need to update the `until` property instead. So, use a different callback in your declaration

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: nextNoon,
        description: '',
        onExpiry: doReset
    });
```

and then

```
function doReset(){
var todaysNoon = new Date(),
        nextNoon = new Date();
    todaysNoon.setHours(14, 00, 0);
    if (todaysNoon <= nextNoon) {
        nextNoon.setDate(nextNoon.getDate() + 1);
    }
    nextNoon.setHours(14, 00, 0);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('change', 'until', nextNoon);//use change method     
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U6tgV/6/) with a timer of 10 seconds for testing